# CASE expression in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I getting an error by using this SQL query. could someone help?

```
select *
    case 
        when TO_CHAR (current_date, 'DY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') = 'TUE' then "today is tuesday"
        else  "today is not tuesday"
    end as Todate
from
    dual
```

The code is just a demo. If it work then I have the plan to implement more things.

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Single quotes around literal strings, like you also do for `'TUE'`

Comment: `"today is not tuesday"` should be `'today is not tuesday'`

Comment: Double quotes are for names, single quotes for string literals. So, you make Oracle think there is a column called "today is tuesday".

Comment: I try to use 'today is not tuesday' also but I got the same error. From keyword not found where expected

Answer (score 2):

As said in the comments, you need to remove the `*` and to edit `"` into `'`:

```
select 
    case 
        when TO_CHAR (current_date, 'DY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') = 'TUE' then 'today is tuesday'
        else  'today is not tuesday'
    end as Todate
from
    dual
```

Comment: @Anh Nguyen: Then click the check sign in order to accept this answer.